# Why is my button not jumping to its intended section in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a question regarding using scrollspy, adding a button inside the navbar, and having that button jump to its intended target section. I added a  tag to be more semantic, and used a  with the class of form-inline to put it next to the navbar links. The nav links work fine, but the button doesn't.

I was trying different ways to add the href to the button tag, or to substitute the  tag with an  tag and removing the  tag, but nothing works. I was trying to find a scrollspy that used the  tag, but no luck. Here's my code:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">
 <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" id="navbar">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="navbarBrand">Unexpected Friends</a>
   <!--navbar toggler is the hamburger icon that appears when in smaller screens-->
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div id="navbarNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <!--ml-auto moves the links to the right-->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#ourStory">Our Story<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <form class="form-inline" id="button">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button" id="waysToHelp" href="#waysToHelp">Ways to Help</button>
        </form>
      </ul>
   </div><!--navbarNav-->

 </nav>

<section id="waysToHelp">
       <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <img src="img/uf_10.jpg" class="img-fluid float-right ml-4">
                  <h1 class="text-center">Ways To Help</h1>
                  <p>Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum. Massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. Pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus. Tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt. Et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim.<br><br>
                  Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque. Tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo. Semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut. Risus at ultrices mi tempus. Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at. Sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit.</p>
              </div><!--column-->
          </div><!--row-->
       </div><!--container-->
     </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly read the documentation properly:
The `data-spy` attribute will be on the div outside the nav with a `data-target` to indicate the selected nav.

> It has to be `a` tag because of href. It converts hash URL,which is also accessible when entered in the URL directly. That is the fundamentals of how it works.

You can do it like -

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button"
id="waysToHelp"><a  href="#waysToHelp">ways to help</a></button>



<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#ourStory">Our Story<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#waysToHelp">ways to help</a>
        </li>
        <form class="form-inline" id="button">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button" id="waysToHelp"><a  href="#waysToHelp">ways to help</a></button>
        </form>
      </ul>
```

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/cvwrfau0/

Comment: I have that, maybe you didn’t understand. My button even with the same id as the section its intended to, won’t jump to its section, no matter what I do. I tried making it an <a> item and it didn’t work either. I did read the documEntation on how to setup the navbar, but for some reason only the button does not work, the other regular <a> link work fine.

Comment: It has to be a tag because of href. It converts hash url,which is also accessible when entered in the url directly. Also the data target and scroll has to be immediate parent.

Comment: If you can make a jsfiddle I can fix in few seconds

Comment: Sure, here you go. Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/HailToTheV612/d9epu3Lk/

Comment: I noticed that when I add an ID to the <a> tag, it doesn't jump to its section anymore, and I was using the ID to customize it. Do you know why that is?

Comment: By adding an ID you mean           <a class="nav-link" id="#waysToHelp">ways to help</a> ? For it to jump it has to follow the above structure and use href.

Comment: Could you mark my answer as correct if it answered your question ? I am looking to get my next badge at 1k rep

Comment: including href. If you add on top of it an id to style it later on css, for some reason the id breaks it and it doesn't work anymore. I got rid of the id but it's a weird bug or whatever